# Google Line Charts interpolateNulls: false breaks chart

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, charts, interpolation

I knew the answer was going to be much simpler then I was making it out to be.  I added the following if statement to the while loop.

```
<?php
                echo "['Month', '$year1' , '$year2' , '$currentYear'],";
                require('./PHPConnect.php');        
                $statement1 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement1)){
                    if($row["Year3"] == NULL ? $row["Year3"] = 'null' : $row["Year3"] = $row["Year3"]);
                    echo "['".$row["Month"]."', ".$row["Year1"].", ".$row["Year2"].", ".$row["Year3"]."],";
                }
                mysqli_close($dbc);
                ?>
```

As an update we now know that the problem is MySql spits out NULL and javascript requires null.  Any thoughts on how to accomplish getting MySql NULL int value into lowercase null.

*I was wondering if anyone can help me with this.  I created a line chart to visual show company sales by month for the current year and the previous 2.  It works fine, but because at this point there is 0 sales for the remaining months of the year it shows a steep drop off for that line.  We don't want to see that, so I tried changing the 0s to nulls in the database and using interpolateNulls false.  However when I add the interpolateNulls option the line chart breaks and no longer displays anything.  Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var data;
        var chart;
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart(){
                data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 
                <?php
                echo "['Month', '$year1' , '$year2' , '$currentYear'],";
                require('./PHPConnect.php');        
                $statement1 = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query1);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statement1)){
                    echo "['".$row["Month"]."', ".$row["Year1"].", ".$row["Year2"].", ".$row["Year3"]."],";
                }
                mysqli_close($dbc);
                ?>
            ]); 
            var options = {
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                title:'Total Sales By Month',
                width:600, 
                height:500,
                interpolateNulls: false,
                legend: {position: 'bottom'}
            };
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```